# Argument of \language@active@arg~ has an extra } when long caption

Tags: captions, arguments

Here is my Preamble:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  
\overrideIEEEmargins
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}         % spanish
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
```

and here the problematic part of the code...

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{4LevelInverter}
    \caption{Inversor multinivel de 4 niveles medio puente para cada nivel de nivel nivel nivel}
    \label{fig:4-level-example}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Literally, when I add more characters to the caption I have the compile error because this next part of code works perfectly:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{4LevelInverter}
    \caption{Inversor multinivel de 4 niveles medio puente para cada nivel}
    \label{fig:4-level-example}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I tried this several times, I am pretty sure by now that adding a longer caption results in the error. The error is the following:

```
Argument of \language@active@arg~ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.198 ...ra cada nivel nvie deni adniue jdaisn ds}
```

They asked me for a complete example so here it goes:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  
\overrideIEEEmargins
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

\title{\LARGE \bf
Title
}

\author{
    authors
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{figure_name}
    \caption{Inversor multinivel de 4 niveles medio puente para cada nivel}
    % This example works good until I make the caption longer in characters. 
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't show only snippets, make a complete example (and replace the graphic by e.g. a rule or a word).

Comment: Ok, done, I attached a complete example at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some general remarks: If you load `graphicx`, you do not have to load `graphics`.
You also do not need `\selectlanguage{spanish}` if you loaded `babel` with the `spanish` option. Additionally `\bf` is deprecated, use `\bfseries` instead.

To your actual question: The version of `ieeeconf` you use is not compatible with the shorthands defined by `babel` for the spanish language. You can fix this by patching `\@makecaption`:

```
\documentclass{ieeeconf}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\makeatletter
% Almost exactly copied from ieeeconf.cls
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \ifx\@captype\@IEEEtablestring
    \begin{center}{\footnotesize #1}\\{\footnotesize\scshape #2}\end{center}%
    \@IEEEtablecaptionsepspace
  \else
    \@IEEEfigurecaptionsepspace
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\footnotesize #1.~~ #2}%
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\footnotesize #1.~~\relax}% <-- The \relax has been added here to make bebel happy
    \parbox[t]{\hsize}{\footnotesize \noindent\unhbox\@tempboxa#2}%
  \else
    \ifcenterfigcaptions \hbox to\hsize{\footnotesize\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
    \else \hbox to\hsize{\footnotesize\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhh Inversor multinivel de 4 niveles medio puente para cada nivel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```